# Unable To Attach Views from XML Layout in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am unable to attach the views from my xml file in onBindViewHolder  of Recycler View in my Adapter. I'm getting the following error:

```
Unresolved reference: ivArticleImage
```

I am using DiffUtil Class.

I Can access them by Binding method but by normal i can't.
SomeBody Plss help!!
here is my XML file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArticleImage"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My adapter class

```kotlin
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ArticleViewHolder>() {
    inner class ArticleViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem.url == newItem.url
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }

    private val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArticleViewHolder {
        return ArticleViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_article, parent, false)
        )
// item_artcile is my XMl file
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticleViewHolder, position: Int) {
       val article = differ.currentList[position]
       holder.itemView.apply {
           Glide.with(this).load(article.urlToImage).into(ivArticleImage)// giving error

        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return differ.currentList.size
    }

}
```

'Article' is My data class..

I tried various method but error was still there
only solution which i was able to find was to use binding method.
but I am not using viewBinding in my project.

Comment: Can you explain what error?

Comment: Unresolved reference: ivArticleImage ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ArticleViewHolder` class doesn't have anything to reach `ivArticleImage` because the `itemView` is just a `View` not a view binding. You have options:

Find the view

```
itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivArticleImage)
```

Expose the binding

```
 inner class ArticleViewHolder(val binding: YourBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

Please remember to update the inflation in `onCreateViewHolder` because now your constructor use a `DataBinding`:

```
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
val binding = YourDataBinding.inflate(inflater, ...)
return ArticleViewHolder(binding)
```

And you can do what you want with a minimal change

```
holder.binding.apply {

       Glide.with(this).load(article.urlToImage).into(ivArticleImage)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@cutiko's answer is correct if you are using view binding. If you are not using it, you can just extend your view holder like this:

```
inner class ArticleViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val myImageView = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivArticleImage)
}
```

Then later access your imageView:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticleViewHolder, position: Int) {
   val article = differ.currentList[position]
   Glide.with(holder.myImageView).load(article.urlToImage).into(holder.myImageView)
}
```